# What is the difference between getText() and getSelection() of SWT Spinner?

Tags: java, swt, spinner

For a `Spinner` control in SWT, what is the difference between `getText()` and `getSelection()`? The only thing I can make out is the return type. However, I cannot enter any text, only numbers are allowed.

> **getText():**
>   Returns a string containing a copy of the contents of the receiver's text field, or an empty string if there are no contents.
>
> **getSelection():**
>   Returns the selection, which is the receiver's position.

So why do we have two different getters and which one should I use?

Comment: If you feel one of the answers solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Alternatively, write an answer of your own that summarizes the findings and mark it as accepted. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Spinner` represents a numeric selection, you should go with `getSelection()` as it returns exactly what has been selected.

I don't know why `getText()` exists, but it'll return the `String` representation of the selected value, e.g. if `getSelection()` returns the `int` `7`, `getText()` will return the `String` `"7"`.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation states, `getText()` returns the string as if is currently displayed, including possible non-numeric values or values outside the min/max range. `getSelection()` returns the current or last valid integer value.

Usually, you would want to use `getSelection()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is it possible for the `Spinner` to have non-numeric values?

Comment: @Baz Spinner on the Mac certainly allows non-numeric values. The macOS Spinner isn't a native control as macOS doesn't seem to use spinners.

Comment: @greg-449 That's good to know. On Windows you can't enter non-numeric values. Can't check Linux just now.

Comment: On Windows I can neither enter non-numeric values, nor leave the spinner empty. That is why I was wondering, why there is such a thing as ``getText()`` anyway. But if other platforms handle this differently, it seems perfectly fine to have two methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. `getText` specifically says it can be empty (I'd guess it depends on platform whether this ever happens). It then allows to distinguish this case from value 0.
2. You could use `getText` when using `Spinner` with decimal digits (see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Spinner.html#setDigits(int)), since `getSelection` in this case is farther from the meaning of the value. But note that the decimal separator depends on the current locale.

Comment: Good point. I'd still recommend using `getSelection()` and "adjusting" the result by using `getDigits()` rather than parsing the `String` returned from `getText()`.

Comment: Be aware that the locale of SWT controls is the current locale of the platform and does not necessarily match the current Java locale which might be another reason to favor `getSelection()`.